# Will using a conditional variable negate execution plan retention and reuse

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to write a stored procedure in SQL Server that utilizes "conditional variables". By conditional, I am referring to something along these lines:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Order_SEL]
    @BeginDate DATETIME = NULL
    , @ENDDATE = NULL = NULL

BEGIN
    SELECT
        ID
        , CustomerID
        , DateOrdered
    FROM
        Orders
    WHERE
        (
        @BeginDate IS NULL
        OR
        DateOrdered BETWEEN @BeginDate AND @EndDate
        )
END
```

Now, I know one of the benefits of using stored procedures is execution plan retention and reuse. Will the methodology used above negate this advantage?

Comment: It will depend on what plan is compiled the first time the procedure is executed and whether the parameters at that time are (a) representative of a large or small number of rows in the table and (b) representative of the parameter values that are supplied much of the time. Please perform a web search for "parameter sniffing" and start with [Erland's article](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html). Since SQL Server can now compile at the statement level, it can make sense to (a) branch using `IF` logic and separate queries or (b) build a query conditionally using dynamic SQL.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Of course! Why would I expect a simple Yes/No answer to _any_ SQL question these days. So basically you are saying: It Depends :)

Comment: That's right, I think usually this will be an unsafe/unreliable way to do it, but in the end it might not matter much depending on your query patterns, size of data, etc. You should test using your data, your hardware, your query patterns, etc. and see if you notice a difference in the plans depending on a wide variety of parameter values, whether the query has a covering index, etc. and make sure to test each variety of parameter after freeing the procedure cache (or at least evicting these specific plans). Recommended on a test system, but not production.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: My actual use-case is to provide a SPROC to support a user-defined search. The user can include up to four or five criteria to define their search. Obviously (I think) creating a SPROC for each and every possible combination is not really feasible. So I might just need to accept any possible performance hit, in lieu of creating a maintenance nightmare. Am I correct in this assumption?

Comment: Please read Erland's article.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: I just read the article and I understand your insistence on having me read it. Thanks again for the help

Comment: Yes sorry it's long but this isn't a simple topic, he summarizes the main issues very well, and translating his words here would not be very beneficial.